# Sync Prod. DB to Upgraded Staging. 1.8.1 to 1.9.1

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, ce-1.9.1.0, upgrade, database-update

I am in the process of Upgrading my Store from 1.8.1 to 1.9.1.

While I can upgrade to 1.9.1, the process along with testing might take about a week. As this is all done in a Staging Environment,

How can I sync the Orders, Customer, Product/Stock Updates etc. that happen in the Production server which is at 1.8.1. ?

Appreciate your time and Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach with upgrades is to upgrade as you are doing on a local environment and fix any issues with themes and modules that arise. Then when you are confident that it is stable and everything is working, repeat the process on the live production server. Obviously you will want to lock down the environment to ensure that no one else accesses it during this upgrade phase.

This way you do not require to worry about syncing between production and testing environments.

Comment: @JohnCuthberth Thanks for your insight. That I believe is the best bet. But this would involve some downtime of the website. And as we all know the word "Down Time" scares the Management. So, wondering if there is any other way this issue is dealt with.

Comment: @MaharshiRaval regardless of your approach you will require downtime. Wether that down time is in the form of running the live production site upgrade or, replacing the live production site with a staging enviroment that has been upgraded and the consequential synchronisation of the user data. (This would need to be done in order to preserve data integrity during the migration of the users from one database to the other otherwise you will end up with stock/ order information being unreliable. Your approach for a script would be essentially to do a loop through all orders above your last order.